# Create site-navigation using D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want like to create a data-driven site-navigation using D3.

My data-structure is as follows:

```
const sidenavData = [
    { 'name': 'Header name 1', 'type': 'header' },
    { 'name': 'Menu item 1', 'type': 'item', 'hasPages': [
            { 'name': 'Page 1' },
            { 'name': 'Page 2' },
        ]
    },
    { 'name': 'Menu item 2', 'type': 'item', 'hasPages': [
            { 'name': 'Report 1' },
            { 'name': 'Report 2' },
            { 'name': 'Report 3' },
        ]
    },
    { 'name': 'Header name 2', 'type': 'header' },
    { 'name': 'Notifications', 'type': 'item' },
    { 'name': 'Messages', 'type': 'item' },
]
```

The output I would like to achieve should look like this:

```
<ul class="sidebar-nav">
    <li class="sidebar-header">Header name 1</li>
    <li class="sidebar-item"><a class="sidebar-link">Menu item 1</a>
        <ul class="sidebar-dropdown">
            <li class="sidebar-item"><a class="sidebar-link">Page 1</a></li>
            <li class="sidebar-item"><a class="sidebar-link">Page 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-item"><a class="sidebar-link">Menu item 2</a>
        <ul class="sidebar-dropdown">
            <li class="sidebar-item"><a class="sidebar-link">Report 1</a></li>
            <li class="sidebar-item"><a class="sidebar-link">Report 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-header">Header name 2</li>
    <li class="sidebar-item"><a class="sidebar-link">Notifications</a></li>
    <li class="sidebar-item"><a class="sidebar-link">Messages</a></li>
</ul>
```

My code looks like this:

```
var nav = d3.select('ul.sidebar-nav');
nav
    .selectAll('li')
    .data(sidenavData).enter()
    .append('li')
    .attr('class', d => d.type == 'header' ? 'sidebar-header' : 'sidebar-item')
    .text(d => d.type == 'header' ? d.name : null);

var items = nav
    .selectAll('li.sidebar-item')
    .append('a')
    .attr('class', 'sidebar-link')
    .text(d => d.name);

var dropdowns = items
    .append('ul')
    .attr('class', 'sidebar-dropdown');

var dropdownItems = dropdowns.selectAll('li.sidebar-item')
    .data(d => d.hasItems).enter()   // this seems to be the issue??
    .append('li')
    .attr('class','sidebar-item');
```

When I run the code, I get an error: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not iterable.`

It seems as though I cannot assign the nested data (d.hasPages) to create de dropdownItems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello if you only need to generate it once and have only 2 level of nested lists, I would do something like this:

```
var nav = d3.select('ul.sidebar-nav');
nav.selectAll('li')
  .data(sidenavData)
  .enter()
  .append('li')
  .attr('class', d => d.type == 'header' ? 'sidebar-header' : 'sidebar-item')
  .each(function(d) {
    let li = d3.select(this);
    if (d.type == 'header') {
      li.text(d.name)
    } else if (d.hasPages) {
      li.append('ul')
        .attr('class', 'sidebar-dropdown')
        .selectAll('li')
        .data(d.hasPages)
        .enter()
        .append('li')
        .attr('class', 'sidebar-item')
        .append('a')
        .attr('class', 'sidebar-link')
        .text(da => da.name)
    } else {
      li.append('a')
        .attr('class', 'sidebar-link')
        .text(d.name)
    }
  })
```

```js
const sidenavData = [{
    'name': 'Header name 1',
    'type': 'header'
  },
  {
    'name': 'Menu item 1',
    'type': 'item',
    'hasPages': [{
        'name': 'Page 1'
      },
      {
        'name': 'Page 2'
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    'name': 'Menu item 2',
    'type': 'item',
    'hasPages': [{
        'name': 'Report 1'
      },
      {
        'name': 'Report 2'
      },
      {
        'name': 'Report 3'
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    'name': 'Header name 2',
    'type': 'header'
  },
  {
    'name': 'Notifications',
    'type': 'item'
  },
  {
    'name': 'Messages',
    'type': 'item'
  },
];

var nav = d3.select('ul.sidebar-nav');
nav.selectAll('li')
  .data(sidenavData)
  .enter()
  .append('li')
  .attr('class', d => d.type == 'header' ? 'sidebar-header' : 'sidebar-item')
  .each(function(d) {
    let li = d3.select(this);
    if (d.type == 'header') {
      li.text(d.name)
    } else if (d.hasPages) {
      li.append('ul')
        .attr('class', 'sidebar-dropdown')
        .selectAll('li')
        .data(d.hasPages)
        .enter()
        .append('li')
        .attr('class', 'sidebar-item')
        .append('a') 
        .attr('class', 'sidebar-link')
        .text(da => da.name)
    } else {
      li.append('a')
        .attr('class', 'sidebar-link')
        .text(d.name)
    }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <title>multibar d3</title>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <ul class="sidebar-nav"></ul>




</body>

</html>
```